# input selector convert jquery code to javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, input

i tried to convert `jquery` code to `javascript` but i cant figure out how to write this one in `javascript`

**JQuery Code**

```
$('<input type="file" accept="image/*" />')
```

i want to conver this code into `javascript`

**tried code**

```
var uploader = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
```

and after that fire click event of `uploader` but cant working

**click function code**

```
uploader[0].click(function(){
   console.log('test');
});
uploader.click(function(){
   console.log('test');
});
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: `document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').click();` needs to be work for you. show us `click` code and explain about the problem please.

Comment: @AlivetoDie updated my code. please check.

Comment: what is `i` variable? where have you defined that?

Comment: @ricky i have used add more image option. so i loop through its parent div

Comment: remove this code `uploader[0].click(function(){
   console.log('test');
});` it should work fine

Comment: @ricky i write because i tried both code with `[0]` and without it its not working

Comment: If you want all the upload selector element then you should use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`

Comment: check the mdn site https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click. You can not pass any argument in this function

Comment: @ricky but i have not create `input type='file'` i will add run time and click this

Comment: In that scenario by seeing the error what I can assume is you are trying to access the `input element` from DOM before rendering it actually.
Can you post your complete code

Comment: if you put your code inside `setTimeout(function(){ /here/ }, 0)` it should work

Answer (score 0):

A function `.click` imitates mouse click on element. You need to use `.onclick` handler
There are two ways to do it:

1. Set property onclick of element `uploader.onclick = function()...`

```js
var uploader = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

uploader.onclick = function(e){
  console.log('Hello!', e.target);
};
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

2. Set handler for onclick event `uploader.addEventListener('click', fucntion()...`

```js
var uploader = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

uploader.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log('Hello!', e.target);
});
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

addEventListener does not overwrite existing event handlers on elements, whereas onclick overrides any existing onclick = function event handlers.

addEventListener does not works in older versions of Internet Explorer ( > IE 9 ) which uses attachEvent instead ( < IE 9 ), whereas onclick works all the browsers.

3. Here is the way to treat events on dynamically added elements - you can bind an event listener to `body` and check the clicked element for matching the criteria.

By this way event listener doesn't overlap another handlers bound to body.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if (e.target.tagName == 'INPUT' && e.target.type == 'file') {
    var newElement = document.createElement('INPUT');
    newElement.type = 'file';
    document.body.appendChild(newElement);
    console.log('Hello!', e.target);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" class="field" />
```

Comment: but i dont have `<input type="file" accept="image/*" />` and add runtime then what code will be used?

Comment: you wrote `$('<input type="file" accept="image/*" />')`, thus I supposed you need to handle event on this element. Which element do you need to trap?

Comment: I've added some explanation about these ways difference

Comment: but i dont use `jquery`

Comment: I've added a way to handle event on dynamicalyy added elements.